# Android Home Screen widget ImageView radius

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I want to give rounded corners to my `ImageView` in Android with XML. I tried all the other solutions (`CardView` and `ShapeableImageView`) but none of them worked.

This is my current code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_background"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:id="@+id/widget_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/default_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#E9E9E9"
        tools:text="Nothing yet!" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scribb_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/image_background"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`image_background.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="11dp"/>
</shape>
```

`widget_background.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#222122"/>
    <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="7dip" android:color="#9031AA"/>
</shape>
```

I am trying this in a Home Screen Widget and afaik `CardView` and `ShapeableImageView` are not supported. I also don't want to use `android:clipToOutline` as it's not supported in Android API versions under 31. I will be happy to provide other code if required.